# Node.js filter array with multiple terms

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, filter

I have a files array that contains a set of text files in this format:

[test/fixtureData/fixtureData2/test3.inc,
test/fixtureData/fixtureData3/test5.inc,
test/fixtureData/test1.inc,
,test/fixtureData/test6.ssi
,test/fixtureData/test9.html]

I want to filter this array so that it filters out '.ssi' and '.html' files. And the code below:

```
var recursiveReadSync = require('recursive-readdir-sync'),
var fs = require('fs');

var foundFiles = [];
var files = fs.readdirSync(url);
```

I've recursed through a file and for simplicity of not pasting my whole code, assume the files array contains the items as listed above. I'm not sure how to filter this files array, i've looked at a few nodeJS api's and haven't found anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.filter` is what you are looking for (if you only want the ssi/inc files, remove the not operator `!`):

```
files.filter(function(fileName) {
   return !fileName.match(/\.(inc|ssi)$/);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution without using regex, and using `path` module:

```
var path = require('path');
var filteredFiles = files.filter(function(value) {
    var ext = path.extname(value);
    return ['.inc', '.ssi'].indexOf(ext) == -1;
});
```

This is easier to maintain if you want the list of restricted extensions to be configurable.